# is there a way to build a react app in a single html file?

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a react app and have the static css and js files effectively embedded into the *index.html* that gets produced when I call `yarn build`.

I can obviously hack the output and replace the `<script src"...` and `<link href="/static/css/...` tags with inline versions but was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you want one single html file?

Answer (score 26):

I got it working.  For future reference (using react 16.7.0 & yarn 1.10.1)...

Create a react app:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn build
```

All good?  Cool, run `eject` so that you have access to the webpack config:

```
yarn eject
rm -rf build node_modules
yarn install
yarn build
```

Add this project and update webpack:

```
yarn add html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.4
yarn add html-webpack-inline-source-plugin@1.0.0-beta.2
```

Edit `config/webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin'); <--- add this
...
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
    Object.assign(
      ...
      isEnvProduction
        ? {
            inlineSource: '.(js|css)$', <-- add this
            minify: {
              ...
  ),
  ...
  isEnvProduction &&
    shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin), <--- add this
    new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime~.+[.]js/]),
    ...
```

Run `rm -rf build && yarn build && serve -s build` - the `index.html` you load should now contain all the js and css stuff inline.  Note that the static files are still created in the build dir, but they aren't used by the page.

Answer (score 13):

Previous answers don't work because `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` is no longer supported by the author, replaced by official plugins `html-inline-script-webpack-plugin` and `html-inline-css-webpack-plugin`. The following method works with the latest React 17 as of October 2021. Steps:

Create a React app

```
create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
yarn
yarn start
```

Make sure it's working, you're happy with the output. Then, eject your config (I think this can be done without ejecting config, but I can't be bothered to look up how to configure CRA)

```
yarn eject
rm -rf build node_modules
yarn
yarn build
```

Then, add the Webpack plugins (Assuming you want both CSS and scripts embedded here, just remove one if you only want the other)

```
yarn add html-inline-css-webpack-plugin -D
yarn add html-inline-script-webpack-plugin -D
```

Finally, add these to the Webpack config `config/webpack.config.js`. Firstly declare them at the top of the file:

```
const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require('html-inline-css-webpack-plugin').default;
const HtmlInlineScriptPlugin = require('html-inline-script-webpack-plugin');
```

Then add them to the `plugins: [...]` collection. Search for `new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin` and add them just after that:

```
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(),
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new HtmlInlineScriptPlugin(),
```

Note: **It is important to include the `isEnvProduction` / `shouldInlineRuntimeChunk` checks**! If you skip these the hot refresh won't work when you run `yarn start`. You only want to embed the scripts in production mode, not during development.

Now, if you run `yarn build` you'll find all the CSS and JS embedded in `build/index.html`. If you run `yarn start` it'll start a hot-reloading dev environment you can develop in.

Comment: After performing these steps it looks to have inlined everything into my index.html file correctly, however, the release index.html file in the build directory doesn't load properly now and just shows a blank white screen. Any idea what could be the issue here? I am very much a newbie to the this world.

Comment: You probably have to add this to your HtmlWebpackPlugin configuration inside your webpack.config.js. Look for the `inject` property and change it's value to `body`. This makes sure that your JavaScript is loaded after your HTML is done loading. The issue your probably having is that your script is loaded before your HTML is ready.

Comment: Thanks @StanleyThijssen, I wasn't able to change the `inject` property's value to `body` (it looks like a boolean in my project), but you were spot on the mark with your reasoning - after moving my inline script to the last line of the HTML `<body>`, it loads as expected. Big kudos!

Comment: @notanalien replace inject: true,   

with inject: "body",

Comment: I followed these steps and also got the blank screen with this error: `createRoot(...): Target container is not a DOM element.`

Adding `inject: 'body'` to the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` fixed this.  

However I still had issues with broken links to static assets.  I fixed this by setting the PUBLIC_URL env var to `.`, e.g.:

`"build": "PUBLIC_URL=. node scripts/build.js",`

Comment: Hooray, thank you very much @Jansky, it works. I provided also an answer that extends on your solution, basically achieving this via react-app-rewired so not to eject or mess with react-scripts config directly.

Answer (score 9):

### 2023 Update

The plugin originally linked below is no longer maintained. There have been multiple forks to update but none of them seem to be actively maintained either. The most recent option supporting Webpack 5 is the following:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin-next

Per its README, it works the same way as the original plugin. Specify:

```js
var HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin-next');
```

Then you can pass in the plugins as before.

---

There is a Webpack plugin that has been created for this purpose:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin

As the README specifies, this must be used with html-webpack-plugin, and you have to specify the `inlineSource` that is passed in:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
    }),
  new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get this working.  Have added html-webpack-inline-source-plugin and html-webpack-plugin to my devDependencies, and have created a webpack.config.js file (though not sure exactly what needs to be in there).  But the build ignores it.

Comment: Ah, it was my assumption you were using webpack already. Do you know what's compiling it under the hood? Are you using something like create-react-app?

Comment: An update in 2021, we can replace `new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()` to `new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin)` to get it work.

Comment: This is no longer valid/working solution for webpack5/react17. There is an issue there that shows what errors you will get: https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin/issues/79#issuecomment-1222361171

You can no longer pass arguments to HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get it working with all of the supplied answers. However, I want to help anyone trying to find the solution by providing some links that I found corresponding to this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407

[Generate single physical javascript file using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123097/generate-single-physical-javascript-file-using-create-react-app)

[Inline CSS with Webpack, without HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490604/inline-css-with-webpack-without-htmlwebpackinlinesourceplugin)

https://pangyiwei.medium.com/building-a-react-app-as-a-single-html-file-with-create-react-app-no-eject-283a141e7635

https://www.labnol.org/code/bundle-react-app-single-file-200514

For my very simple use case minification etc. is not as important so I will just use this modified version of the [react website](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute) example (example download [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/6668a1f6986742109c00a581ce704605/archive/87f0b6f34238595b44308acfb86df6ea43669c08.zip)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
  <p>This page demonstrates using React with no build tooling.</p>
  <p>React is loaded as a script tag.</p>

  <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
  <div id="root"></div>

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel">
    'use strict';
    class LikeButton extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { liked: false };
      }

      render() {
        if (this.state.liked) {
          return 'You liked this.';
        }

        return <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true })} > Like </button >;
      }
    }
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

    root.render(<LikeButton />)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

@Jansky answer works for me, hooray! However, I want to follow up as there is a way to do these modifications without ejecting app or messing with `react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` file. And that includes Overriding HtmlWebpackPlugin to inline script within body.

Others can't get this to work probably because creating webpack.config.js within own project which is not used when using create-react-app.

This works for me with webpack5, react17

1. Install react-app-rewired that allows overriding webpack config

```
npm install react-app-rewired --save-dev
```

2. Read [readme.md](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#how-to-rewire-your-create-react-app-project) to see that you have to update scripts to invoke `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts`

```
  /* package.json */

  "scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
+   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
+   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
-   "test": "react-scripts test",
+   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

3. Create `config-overrides.js` with this content

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlInlineCssWebpackPlugin = require('html-inline-css-webpack-plugin').default;
const HtmlInlineScriptPlugin = require('html-inline-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpack: function (config, env) {
    //inline css and scripts right after chunk plugin.
    //chunk plugin will not be present for development build and thats ok.
    const inlineChunkHtmlPlugin = config.plugins.find(element => element.constructor.name === "InlineChunkHtmlPlugin");
    if (inlineChunkHtmlPlugin) {
      config.plugins.splice(config.plugins.indexOf(inlineChunkHtmlPlugin), 0,
        new HtmlInlineCssWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlInlineScriptPlugin()
      );
    }
    
    //Override HtmlWebpack plugin with preserving all options and modifying what we want
    const htmlWebpackPlugin = config.plugins.find(element => element.constructor.name === "HtmlWebpackPlugin");
    config.plugins.splice(config.plugins.indexOf(htmlWebpackPlugin), 1,
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
          ...htmlWebpackPlugin.userOptions,
          inject: 'body'
        }
      )
    );

    return config;
  }
}
```