# Create React App - generate a single file

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I would like to create an HTML report using React.
The report is not being served by the server, its being sent to the user as plain HTML.

The problem is that when I run 'npm run build', there are additional 'js' files created in the 'static' folder and I want that the user will get the report in one HTML file.

Is there a tool that can merge all the 'js' files and integrating it in the index.html file while I am building the app?

The final result is the following:
The user will get only 1 index.html to his mail.

Undesired result:
The user will get the index.html + the regular 'static' folder via the mail.

I have found a similar solution that shows how to bundle the all the 'js' files into one file, its very close to what I want but not entirely, I need to have exactly one file.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a solution that might be useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344207/4988674

Comment: Look exactly what I require. Thanks