# Inline CSS with Webpack, without HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

We had been using `HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin` without issue but it's no longer supported so we moved to `InlineChunkHtmlPlugin` which works great for JS, but refuses to capture the output `style.css` file and inline it, leaving us with no styles.

Is there some way to inline CSS without building a crude custom solution?

There's many questions similar to mine, but all answers I've found rely on the now unmaintained `HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin` plugin.

```js
  const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
  const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');
  const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');

  module.exports = {
    //  ... our other configuration options, loaders, etc
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'style.css',
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './template.html',
        // inject: 'body',
        inject: true,
        filename: './output.html',
        inlineSource: '.(js|css)$',
        chunks: ['chunk'],
     }),
      // new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(); // Used to work for loading JS & CSS
      new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/.*/]); // Only loads JS, no CSS -- https://openbase.io/js/react-dev-utils
    ],


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`yarn add`[`html-inline-css-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/Runjuu/html-inline-css-webpack-plugin)`--dev`

```js
  const HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin = require('html-inline-css-webpack-plugin').default; // Require the plugin
  // ... 
  // ...
  new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/.*/]); // Your existing InlineChunkHtmlPlugin
  new HTMLInlineCSSWebpackPlugin(); // Add this new line after InlineChunkHtmlPlugin
```

All of your code should be otherwise the same. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Did you use react eject? before customizing this?

Comment: I don't use Create React App, sorry. I think traditional wisdom is that you need to reject, [but maybe you don't have to?](https://dev.to/nodewarrior/override-cra-and-add-webpack-config-without-ejecting-2f3n) I can't give an answer with certainty..

Comment: Yeah I followed that approach after posting this comment. Thanks for the reply :) I am getting 404 error when I hit the generated HTML page. did you face anything like that?

Comment: I build for [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/), not web, so I couldn't say. Sorry.