# How can I extract react code into a single runnable HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to extract a React application into a single runnable HTML file to save it on the server and pass it around using FTP. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried building the React project? It will not be a single file though, it will give you at least two files one HTML and another js

Comment: You have to modify the webpack there are some solution to do this but I don't recommend this way.
Here is related solutions=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949719/is-there-a-way-to-build-a-react-app-in-a-single-html-file