# combine react build output into single js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123097/generate-single-physical-javascript-file-using-create-react-app) however neither of the answers solves the problem.

After running `npm run build` the resultant `index.html` looks similar to:

```
<script>!function (i) { function e(e) { for //rest omitted
<script src="/static/js/2.3f294f32.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.7b9daa35.chunk.js"></script>
```

The first `<script>` element is inlined javascript that i have extracted to a file called `loader.js`

```
<script src="/loader.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/2.3f294f32.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/main.7b9daa35.chunk.js"></script>
```

this works but I would like to combine *all 3 files into a single file*

I've tried [filesmerge.com](https://www.filesmerge.com/merge-javascript-files) to combine the JS files but this results in an error when referencing the single file:

```
output.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
at output.min.js:1
```

I then tried combining using [jscompress.com](https://jscompress.com/) and whilst this does not produce any errors the react root element is not rendered

I've also tried [this solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407) suggested on the create-react-app repo which does not work. No error is produced but no react element is rendered (page remains blank)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Brief

In short: **It's possible, but not very practical**. Why? Your application will no longer be performant as your single bundle file grows. A single large request, instead of smaller requests, will inevitably lead to slower web performance and potentially wasted bandwidth.

On that same note, I'd highly advise **against using the CRA for your single-bundled application**. While the CRA is a great boilerplate geared toward a DX friendly approach to React with Webpack, it does contain a lot of dependencies that may be unnecessarily bundled with your app.

As such, I'd **highly recommend** building your own Webpack configuration (it's relatively simple with the help of the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) combined with the [CRA Webpack notes](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js)) or consider alternatives like [rollup](https://www.rollupjs.org/guide/en/), [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp), [microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle), or [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) to name a few.

The following procedure below will inevitably become outdated as the CRA gets updated. Therefore, use these instructions at your own risk.

### Procedure

**CRA Version: v4.0.3**

You'll first want to eject: `yarn eject` or `npm run eject` -- you can probably use some 3rd party packages to override without ejecting, but I'll leave that up to you to figure out.

Then, you'll need to go to the `config/webpack.config.js` file and change the following:

- Remove the **InlineChunkHtmlPlugin** import from top imports and under **plugins**, remove `isEnvProduction && shouldInlineRuntimeChunk && new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/])` as it creates a chunk file list inside the `index.html` file when building
- Under **plugins**, change **MiniCssExtractPlugin** options to only output a single css file by changing **filename** to `filename: "static/css/bundle.min.css"` and removing the **chunkFileName** option.
- Under  **output**, change **filename** to `filename: "static/js/bundle.min.js"` to output to a single filename for production.
- Under **output**, remove the **chunkFilename** property as you're no longer chunking JS files
- Under **optimization**, remove **splitChunks** property as you're no longer splitting JS chunks
- Under **optimization**, set **runtimeChunk** to `runtimeChunk: false` to avoid creating a `runtime.chunk.js` file
- Under **optimization**, after the **TerserPlugin**, add `new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({ maxChunks: 1 })` to limit outputted chunks to 1

### Demo

**CRA Version: v4.0.3** (demo updated as May 25th, 2021)

**Working repo**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/cra-single-bundle

### Notes

This configuration will inevitably become outdated as the dev world adopts Webpack 5

Comment: that was certainly non-trivial - i'm doing this so i can make a widget that can be easily added to 3rd party websites. just a few notes; there was no `optimizations` section in my `webpack.config.js` (did you mean `optimization`?) however there were dedicated `splitChunks` and `runtimeChunk` fields which i removed - for the diff see here https://www.diffchecker.com/7a1Hdg3a
thanks for your post that is some A+ code and instructions

Comment: Ah, good catch, spelling mistake... should be `optimization`. Updated answer.

Comment: If I wanted to bundle the CSS and JS together (working on a react widget), how would I do that?

Comment: Not familiar with widgets. That said, if you're talking about a single bundle file that includes both JS and the CSS, then it's not possible. The JS and the CSS would need to be requested/imported within the `head` or within a React component. If you're looking for a single bundle file, then you'd want to use a CSS-in-JS solution (like `styled-components`, `styled-jsx` or `react-jss` to name a few) which apply `style` tags to classes during run-time. Also, you may want consider using [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) instead of Webpack as it's more suitable to an NPM library.

Comment: Thanks @MattCarlotta, solid answer.  I've given this a shot and it works great except for one thing.  I'm specifying only one .js file, but I'm getting two: `file.min.js` and `1.file.min.js`.

Comment: Updated answer with new instructions and updated demo for [CRA v4.0.3](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v4.0.3)

Comment: @LuisSerrano See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683116/1107110).

Answer (score 5):

Matt's solution is the closest one I got by now. After a few hours of searching, I found a way to force Webpack to output one js file. Just put it here for future reference or anyone gets this problem.

```
plugins: [
      isEnvProduction &&
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1
      }),
...
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it more easy:

1. Add package `yarn add react-app-rewired`
2. Change scrips section in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
   "test": "react-app-rewired test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

3. create the file `config-overrides.js`

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: function(config, env) {
        config.optimization.splitChunks = {
            cacheGroups: {
               default: false
            }
        };
        config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
        return config;
    }
}
```

From here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-431431877

Comment: To also include styles: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683116/1107110