# Bundle CRA into single js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm having a React App created with CRA, I need to deploy it as a widget.
People need to be able to include a js file and then just use the `<App></App>` Tag where ever they need it. Since CRA splits files I already tried ejecting the app, but failed miserably.

I already tried from similar questions the following:

- [combine-react-build-output-into-single-js-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331493/combine-react-build-output-into-single-js-file)
- [bundling without minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification/55165586#55165586)

the bundling without minification almost got my to the end. But now I would need to minify the resulting file.

This is my build.js file:

```
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
const config = defaults.__get__('config');

// Consolidate chunk files instead
config.optimization.splitChunks = {
  cacheGroups: {
    default: false
  }
};
// Move runtime into bundle instead of separate file
config.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;

// JS
config.output.filename = '[name].js';
// CSS. "5" is MiniCssPlugin
config.plugins[5].options.filename = '[name].css';
config.plugins[5].options.publicPath = '../';
```

this file comes from the [bundling without minification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55165466/how-to-build-a-production-version-of-react-without-minification/55165586#55165586) question. I'm now fairly clueless how to minify it and if it is really the right way to deploy.