# Add React app build to my existing website div

Tags: reactjs, coldfusion

Is it possible to add a build index.html of a React app to a div in my HTML/ColdFusion website?

I built a chatbot in React using hooks.
Bellow is my App.js which imports my ChatBot.js component.

```
import './App.css';
import MyChatBot from './ChatBot';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyChatBot/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It is working. I have a ColdFusion/HTML website where I would like to include this "chatbot" or the generated index.html from `npm run build` to a `div`

```
<!-- ColdFusion Website here --->
<div id="myChatBot"></div>
```

The idea is to have the React application inside that div. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to pass the element ( where you want to mount the react app ) to `ReactDOM.render` method. Then bundle your react app using a bundler, say webpack, and include that bundle via script tag or via the current build process in your app's html.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Website Markup --->
<div id="myChatBot"></div>

<!-- Include React bundle --->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**React**

```
import ReactDOM from "react"
import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("myChatBot"))
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could crate the ```bundle.js```?

Comment: You can use webpack - https://webpack.js.org/ or parcel.If you're using `create-react-app` it already has the process setup - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build

Comment: Yes, I used ```create-react-app``` and I already build my application using ```npm run build```. It generates the index.html (not a bundle.js file).

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to it. Is the ```build/static/js/main.c3b68fb6.chunk.js``` the bundle.js file? Also, should I add ```ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("myChatBot"))``` in my App.js instead of ```export default App;```?

Comment: If you're using CRA then you might have to tweak the process. You can read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331493/combine-react-build-output-into-single-js-file

Comment: Thank you. Th only issue is that I have to include all the .js and .css generated in the static folder. I wish it could generate or combined all in one file

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is helpful to you: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Gist of it is you have import the React scripts and render it to that id:

```js
const domContainer = document.getElementById('myChatBot');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Comment: This example did not work for me because I import external modules in my react app

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#run-jsx-preprocessor Does it not compile the library code?