# Render React Site in a DIV

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

We have site built in react that our client calls (url) and load in a iFrame. We need a mechanism so that the clients can load site in a DIV tag.

We want to provide the HTML/Javascript for our clients (in HTML/Vanilla JavaScript) so that embed our site in a DIV tag rather than iFrame.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66264578/add-react-app-build-to-my-existing-website-div

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add React app build to my existing website div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66264578/add-react-app-build-to-my-existing-website-div)