# How can I create one bundle file from react-create-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, rollup

I am trying to build `react-create-app` into one file (including JS, CSS, PNG, etc...).

It is possible and how?

Should I try to use rollup or it is possible using webpack?

I tested https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin but looks like outdated and not working.

Comment: Check [Disable Code Splitting in CRA2](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#), it might help.

Comment: Simple solution utilizing `react-app-rewired` alongside `customize-cra`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71683116/1107110

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this with CRA (create-react-app) and webpack. I'll detail 3 options below that I've gotten to work.

### Setup - Install react-app-rewired

Each option below makes use of react-app-rewired to be able to customize webpack config within create-react-app without ejecting. As a first step, follow the install instructions on https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#how-to-rewire-your-create-react-app-project

If you already have ejected or you want to eject, you can still use any of the options below, you'll just modify the plugins directly in config/webpack.config.js instead of programmatically through react-app-rewired's config-overrides.js.

Note: two of the options below have `require('html-webpack-plugin')`. Don't yarn add this, to ensure you get the version installed by create-react-app.

### Option 1 - Use [html-webpack-inline-source-plugin](https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin)

For this one, I had to manually specify the latest beta version. When I ran `npm install --save html-webpack-inline-source-plugin` without a version specified, I got version 0.0.10 and it failed.

1. Install react-app-rewired (see Setup section above)
2. `yarn add html-webpack-inline-source-plugin@1.0.0-beta.2`
3. Edit config-overrides.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (env === 'production') {
    config.plugins
      .find(plugin => Object.getPrototypeOf(plugin).constructor.name === 'HtmlWebpackPlugin')
      .options.inlineSource = '.(js|css)$'
    config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin))
  }
  return config
}
```

Note: this plugin is not actively maintained (see the note at top of https://github.com/dustinjackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin#readme) but it works for me.

### Option 2 - Use [script-ext-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/script-ext-html-webpack-plugin) and [style-ext-html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/numical/style-ext-html-webpack-plugin)

1. Install react-app-rewired (see Setup section above)
2. `yarn add script-ext-html-webpack-plugin style-ext-html-webpack-plugin`
3. Edit config-overrides.js:

```
const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin')
const StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (env === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inline: /.+[.]js/
    }))
    config.plugins.push(new StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin())
  }
  return config
}
```

Note: this option will fail (`StyleExtHtmlWebpackPluginError: StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin: could not find ExtractTextWebpackPlugin's generated .css file`) if you don't have any .css files. If so, just comment-out or delete these two lines

```
//const StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('style-ext-html-webpack-plugin')
{...}
    //config.plugins.push(new StyleExtHtmlWebpackPlugin())
```

### Option 3 - Use [react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dev-utils#new-inlinechunkhtmlpluginhtmlwebpackplugin-htmlwebpackplugin-tests-regex)

1. Install react-app-rewired (see Setup section above)
2. (No yarn add needed here, as react-dev-utils is part of create-react-app)
3. Edit config-overrides.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (env === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/.+[.]js/]))
  }
  return config
}
```

Note: this option will only inline js files, not css files.

Answer (score 1):

I've followed [this article](https://www.labnol.org/code/bundle-react-app-single-file-200514) and it worked for me like a charm.

It uses [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) to bundle the whole app in one HTML file.

1. Install: `npm install --save-dev gulp gulp-inline-source gulp-replace`
2. Create `.env` file in the root folder.

```
INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

3. Create a `gulpfile.js` file in the root folder.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const inlinesource = require('gulp-inline-source')
const replace = require('gulp-replace')

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('./build/*.html')
        .pipe(replace('.js"></script>', '.js" inline></script>'))
        .pipe(replace('rel="stylesheet">', 'rel="stylesheet" inline>'))
        .pipe(inlinesource({
            compress: false,
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
});
```

4. Run `npx gulp` (you may include it in your package.json `build` script)

Comment: this gives https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=299 with react-scripts 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to pierre-vr's answer, as of 2024, root.render has to be wrapped in a "DOMContentLoaded" event listener in index.js for Gulp to work.

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
});
```