# How to deploy a single Js after the deployment of React18?

Tags: reactjs

I am using React 18 with create-react-app template and redux-toolkit. I want to deploy a public shareable Url

something like this `https://www.someserverurl.com/CWidget.js`

I just want one shareable Js File including sass/css file.

I tried to make a deployment through npm run build but it create a lot of js, css, json and image files which I don't want.

I want to use Parcel or webpack and gulp.

Can I create a deployment as I mentioned above? I just need a single Js file after the deployment.

I want to use it through simple plain html with javascript. I can simple html page can invoke my widget.

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123097/generate-single-physical-javascript-file-using-create-react-app)

Comment: I just want a single physical js file which can be invoked through html and  javascript

Answer (score 1):

What I think you are looking for is [the public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder).

Everything in the `public/` folder is statically served. No matter if it's JS/HTML/CSS or something else.

Comment: I just want a single physical js file which can be invoked through html and javascript. I couldnt understand what did you say ?  I dont need multiple file , i just need a single js file after the deployment of my react 18 app.